# Update CRM Based UserList, Name and Description

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I'm trying to update my UserList name and description, and I get this error message "USER_LIST_MUTATE_NOT_SUPPORTED".

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <RequestHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/rm/v201809">
            <clientCustomerId xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">xxxxxxxxx</clientCustomerId>
            <developerToken xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</developerToken>
            <userAgent xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">unknown (AwApi-DotNet/24.1.0, Common-Dotnet/9.4.0, .NET CLR/4.0.30319.42000, OAuthServiceAccountFlow, gzip)</userAgent>
        </RequestHeader>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <mutate xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/rm/v201809">
            <operations>
                <operator xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">SET</operator>
                <operand>
                    <id>736365788</id>
                    <name>Audience Google 8 - Update</name>
                    <description>Audience Google 8 - Update</description>
                </operand>
            </operations>
        </mutate>
    </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Double check in Google Ads the list is not one of the lists Google Ads automatically creates. In Google AD web ui navigate to **Tools > Audience Manager > Audience Lists** Under the type column you should see if the list is automatically created, if so then you will need to modify the list which generated this automatic list creation.
- Can you change the list name in Google Ads UI? If so then it might be a permission issue.
- Was the list made via the API? If not could you try creating the list via the API then changing the name and description to see if this works?

Thanks